# Running Spark programs from Eclipse IDE - pom.xml is all good but getting run time errors

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am executing Spark programs from Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS - Eclipse IDE. It's using Oracle Sun JDK 1.8.0_361.
[image]
Referred this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769876/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-scala-productclass)

It's directly executing the Spark programs from Eclipse IDE.
Getting issues for Spark-SQL programs
Regular Spark programs are all working fine.

This program

```
package org.example;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.avg;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max;

public class HousePriceSolution {

    private static final String PRICE = "Price";
    private static final String PRICE_SQ_FT = "Price SQ Ft";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("HousePriceSolution").master("local[1]").getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> realEstate = session.read().option("header", "true").csv("src/main/resources/RealEstate.csv");

        Dataset<Row> castedRealEstate = realEstate.withColumn(PRICE, col(PRICE).cast("long"))
                                                  .withColumn(PRICE_SQ_FT, col(PRICE_SQ_FT).cast("long"));

        castedRealEstate.groupBy("Location")
                        .agg(avg(PRICE_SQ_FT), max(PRICE))
                        .orderBy(col("avg(" + PRICE_SQ_FT + ")").desc())
                        .show();
    }
}
```

and here is the corresponding pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sparkwordcount</groupId>
  <artifactId>sparkwordcount</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>"Spark Word Count"</name>
  
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
<!-- this plugin is for scala code. It uses the version of the Scala library dependency to pick the Scala version -->
<!--
      <plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      -->
    
<!-- this plugin is for java code. the source and target versions are Java versions -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>  
  </build>

  <dependencies>
     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.17</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- the following aren't needed for the word count demo, but
     will be for more complex things.
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- the following artifacts are also avaiable, depending upon
     what you're doing. They would use  the same groupId and version as the ones above:
 spark-mllib
 spark-hive
 spark-catalyst
 spark-streaming-kafka
 spark-repl
 spark-graphx
-->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But I am getting these errors at runtime, build is all good

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
    at org.example.HousePriceSolution.main(HousePriceSolution.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

tried this also but no success
[image]

Comment: You need to use a single Scala version across all dependencies. And this version will be dictated by the one Spark support. Probably 2.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are having a mismatch version between Scala, Spark and KafkaClient. You have the following in your `pom.xml`

```xml
    <!-- scala 2.12.x -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spark using scala 2.13.x -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I guess fixing that, it will solve the problem

Comment: Yes I know there is a mis match but what is the fix?

Comment: You should use the same scala version that you are using as a dependency for all the libraries that you are using to avoid this inconsistency. Which version is the right one depends on the project. I guess setting 2.12 for all of them should solve your problem

Comment: Tried doing this.....but same issue. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
 at org.example.HousePriceSolution.main(HousePriceSolution.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)

Comment: I'm seeing that in all the examples you showed, you have `scala-lang 2.12.x` as dependency (such as in the screenshot and in the `pom.xml` file) and for the spark modules that you are using as dependencies, you are using the suffix `_2.13`, which means they work for `scala-lang 2.13.x`. Have you tried upgrade **scala** to **2.13** or use the spark dependencies that depends on **scala 2.12**?

Comment: In pom.xml - I am having this:<dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.17</version>
    </dependency> where you are seeing _2.13?

Comment: The dependency with the artifact id = `scala-library` is to set which version of scala you want to use in your project. Then you have other dependencies such as `spark-core`, `spark-sql` and `spark-streaming` in your `pom.xml`. At least, that is what I'm seeing in the dependencies showed in the `pom.xml` that is being showed in your question. I can see that all of them have the suffix `_2.13`. Have your tried to replace them for `_2.12`?