# Multiple versions of Scala libraries in pom.xml detected

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

IntelliJ gives me this error message: "Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.12.10 com.twitter:chill_2.12:0.9.3 requires scala version: 2.12.6. Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!"

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can't understand why?

Comment: It might be unrelated but `<artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>` looks like something using 2.11 where everything else is on 2.12.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Spark programs from Eclipse IDE - pom.xml is all good but getting run time errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76386219/running-spark-programs-from-eclipse-ide-pom-xml-is-all-good-but-getting-run-ti)

Comment: @mateusz: it looks like that spark-csv doesn't exists for 2.12 version :-(

Comment: Then you have to downgrade everything else. Scala 2.11, 2.12, 2.13 (and everything before) are virtually different platforms, similar enough that you could migrate source code from one to another (with some effort) but NOT binary compatible with one another and JARs compiled for one version of Scala cannot be used with another version. It changed in Scala 3 and 2.13 artifacts for 2.13 and 3 can be used together, but if you need library that is only compiled on 2.11 you are stuck on 2.11 for everything else.

Comment: However I am not an expect in Spark particularly, and I would ask around. From what I heard some libraries doesn't exist in newer versions of Spark because e.g. some third party provided better implementation or it was merged into core library.